# Traveling salesman problem - negative distances allowed

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, traveling-salesman

I am interested in the following version of TSP:

**Assumption:** TSP where the distances are non-negative. We know the algorithm A which computes the optional solution for such instances of TSP.
**Task:** State an algorithm that uses the algorithm A and computes an optimal solition for instances where negative distances are allowed.

Comment: Are you trying to show a polynomial reduction? Or do you just care about computability? If speed doesn't matter, a brute-force search will work.

Comment: I don't want to show polynomial reduction, i just want to know how to transform instance with negative distances allowed into instance with non-negative distances. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Just change the instance to make smallest weight 0.

Comment: I thought so. I have to find the smallest negative distance and add this value to each distance in graph(each distance >=0). Right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Every TSP tour has the same number of edges. Use this to modify the weights in the graph in a way which affects all TSP tours in the same way.

Comment: Sorry, but i can't get it. What did you mean by this answer?

Comment: That's why it's a hint.

Comment: @Dominik_svk: this answer means that the absolute value of the weights does not matter (hence negative signs are not problematic). All that counts is the differences between the weights (i.e. the effect of trading an edge for another).

Answer (score 0):

If you have n cities, and you increase every single distance by the same amount d, then the length of every tour is increased by the same amount n x d. So whether tour A is better than tour B or not is unchanged, and the optimal tour stays the same. For the decision problem: instead of deciding whether there is a tour of length K, you decide if there is one of length K + n x d.

To handle negative distance, find d’ = most negative distance, and let d = -d’. You can also enforce that the distances all follow the triangular equation by picking a larger d.